# Allure report consist test cases which is not in suite any more

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, webdriver-io, allure

I am using allure with webdriverio  and mocha.After generate and opening. The report consist test cases which is not in test suite any more. Tried allure generate --clean but still getting the same result. When i delete every thing from allure result then it works .[image: Test cases with red cross does not exist in test suite]

Comment: Test cases with red cross does  not exist in test suite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clean up the `allure-results` directory after each test run. You can do that manually, or prepend it to whatever command you're using to run your test. For example, if you're using npm scripts, you could do something like:

```
"scripts": {
  "pretest": "rimraf allure-results",
  "test": "wdio"
}
```

This uses the 'rimraf' npm module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf